# Login using Auth in Laravel 5.4 with or condition

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have login form with 2 fields. First can take both email or mobile a nd second one is password.

How can I check this using auth ?

my code snippet is:-

```
if ( Auth::check([
            'email' => $request->email, 
            'mobile' => $request->email, 
            'password' => $request->password,
            false, 
            false
        ])) 
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return $user;
    }
```

But this thing is combining the keys with and operator. How can I achieve email Or mobile and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition before `Auth::check()` to detect format of provided login (email or mobile). First, change field name to login. Next:

```php
$credentials = [];
if (filter_var($request->login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $credentials['email'] = $request->login;
} else {
    $credentials['mobile'] = $request->login;
}
if ( Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return $user;
}
```

And remember to use `Auth::attempt()` instead of `Auth::check()` that checking if the user is already logged.